# SQLAlchemy: How to select max from several tables

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am starting to use sqlalchemy in an ORM way rather than in an SQL way. I have been through the doc quickly but I don't find how to easily do the equivalent of SQL:

```
select max(Table1.Date) from Table1, Table2
where...
```

I can do:

```
session.query(Table1, Table2)
...
order_by(Table1.c.Date.desc())
```

and then select the first row but it must be quite inefficient. Could anyone tell me what is the proper way to select the max?

Many thanks

Comment: you can use **max** for this(http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/functions.html?highlight=max#sqlalchemy.sql.functions.max)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally one would know the other parts of the query. But without any additional information, below should do it

```
import sqlalchemy as sa

q = (
    session
    .query(sa.func.max(Table1.date))
    .select_from(Table1, Table2)  # or any other `.join(Table2)` would do
    .filter(...)
    .order_by(Table1.c.Date.desc())
)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I was missing query().select_from()